# No hard drive detected during Debian installation

Tags: drivers, debian, raid, sata

I'm having problem in installing debian 7.5.0 on Supermicro server running on raid 1 whereby the hard drive is not detected. This server is running 2x 600GB hdd and i'm using DVD images of debian-7.5.0-amd64 and set boot into the thumbdrive due to the server does not have any cd drives. The installation went ok until i reached into partition section whereby the drives is not there to be selected

Can i know what should i do? How can i load sata drivers upon installation? please help me thx

My server details:
Supermicro SC813MTQ-R400CB
Supermicro X10SLL-F motherboard
Areca Raid Controller
8GB Ram
2x 600GB HDD

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have the RAID device configured in the on-board RAID controller's BIOS and you actually *see* this device as handed off to the BIOS at the server's POST boot stage? I'm asking because Debian (Linux, actually) should not be concerned about the details of your hardware because all it has to know is the SATA (II or III) interface, which it does. But this means your RAID drive should be configured correctly.

Comment: Oh, you mean you have an external RAID controller? Then it's full model number is required to try to get further with this problem.